# Sum of elements of multiple matrices

Tags: r

I have some matrices of equal dimensions.  Some values are missing or NA.

```
 matrix1

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]   NA    2


 matrix2

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   NA
 [2,]   NA    0

 matrix3

       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    0
 [2,]    3   NA
```

Expected output

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    0
[2,]    3    2
```

Tried A + B +C  which is not correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `m1`, `m2`, `m3` are matrices

```
 matrix(mapply(sum, m1,m2,m3, MoreArgs=list(na.rm=T)),ncol=2)
 #      [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    2    0
 #[2,]    3    2
```

Or

```
 Reduce(`+`, lapply(list(m1,m2,m3),function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <-0;x}))
 #       [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    2    0
 #[2,]    3    2
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved by putting the matrices into an `array` first (of 2 rows, 2 columns, and 3 strata), and then `sum`ming within each row and column (`1:2`) of each stratum, with `NA` values removed by `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
apply(array(c(m1,m2,m3),dim=c(2,2,3)),1:2,sum,na.rm=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    0
#[2,]    3    2
```